# How to make Php application running on Xampp to connect to a remote mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a php application running on XAMPP but I want to connect to a mysql db running on a remote machine(which is also using XAMPP). The application works fine when I connect to the mysqldb instance on my machine. I have changed the configuration files to point to the remote db and have given the correct credentials as well. But I get access denied error.

Comment: Chances are that's because the remote machine's DB isn't allowing outside connections. XAMPP is designed as a local development environment, not a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Access denied" means you're at least connecting to the remote MySQL instance. Most like you've got a mismatch on the credentials. You may have granted permissions to "user@somehost" on the remote MySQL, but if that machine can't resolve "somehost" via DNS or a Hosts file lookup, it'll have to fall back to checking for a "user@ip.add.re.ss" account.

Answer (score 1):

First I would check the remote database owner / host to make sure they allow external access. Most hosts, especially shared hosting providers, only allow access to scripts run locally and **do not** allow external access like you are describing.